# How to convert this JSON to a more tractable structure in Pandas

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of json files representing bicycle riding activities (from [Strava](http://strava.com) website API).

When I open the files with `pandas.io.json.read_json(filenme)` I get this result

```
"Printing DataFrame:"
Data columns (total 11 columns):
altitude           33286  non-null values
distance           33286  non-null values
grade_smooth       33286  non-null values
latlng             33286  non-null values
moving             33286  non-null values
outlier            33286  non-null values
resting            33286  non-null values
time               33286  non-null values
total_elevation    33286  non-null values
velocity_smooth    33286  non-null values
watts_calc         33286  non-null values
dtypes: bool(3), float64(5), int64(2), object(1)

"printing single row (df.ix[0]):"
altitude                              699.2
distance                                  0
grade_smooth                              9
latlng             [-28.234746, -52.380721]
moving                                False
outlier                               False
resting                               False
time                                      0
total_elevation                           0
velocity_smooth                           0
watts_calc                                0
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

However, I would like to perform two important modifications to enhance my workflow:

1. split latlng (currently read as `object` type) in two `float64` columns named "lat" and "lon";
2. transform "time" - which represents second elapsed from start time - in `datetime64` datatype, and make it the index. In another script, I did this with `[start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds = t) for t in json_activity['time']]`;
3. take only some columns (time, altitude, lat, lon, distance), not considering others.

I took a look at the docs, but they were as confusing as the last time I tried to use pandas one year ago...

EDIT: I have the following code that gives me what I want, but smells hackyish to me:

```
activity = json.load(open(fname))

datetimestring = fname.split(' - ')[0]  # start time is taken from filename
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimestring, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
time = numpy.array([start + datetime.timedelta(seconds = t) for t in activity['time']])

lat,lon = numpy.hsplit(numpy.array(activity['latlng'], dtype=float), 2)

dist = numpy.array(activity['distance'], dtype=float)/1000.0

speed = numpy.array(activity['velocity_smooth'], dtype=float)

df = pandas.DataFrame({'dist': dist,
                       'lat': lat.ravel(),
                       'lon': lon.ravel()},
                       index=time)

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Do you care about the original `activity` dataframe? You can add your computed columns to the original dataframe and just select them as a view rather than creating a new dataframe from a copy of the data. I don't know if the calculations can be more efficient than your efforts, you should profile the pandas equivalent but I suspect they may not be much difference

Comment: @EdChum please note that `activity` is not a pandas dataframe, it's a python dictionary loaded from a JSON file. `df` is the actual dataframe, which is created from arrays, which themselves are created from the dictionary. When you mention "pandas equivalent", not that the dataframe created with `read_json` is very different.